# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Cookies not appended Razor Pages C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, razor-pages

Cookies are not being appended to the page with the following code, I have tried adding IsEssential to the options but it did not work. Using Asp.Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages. Here's most of my startup.cs and appending cookie code.

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                 .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();


}
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseRequestLocalization();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.useAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        }
```

Adding Cookie

```
            string key = "Cookie";
            var cookieValue = Request.Cookies[key];
            if(cookieValue == null)
            {
                string value = "true";
                var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions()
                {
                    Path = "/",
                    HttpOnly = false,
                    IsEssential = true,
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                };
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, cookieOptions);
            }
```

Recommendations were to add IsEssential to override the CookiePolicy but that didn't solve anything.
Devtools applications show only .AspNetCore.Identity.Application and .AspNetCore.Antiforgery cookies.

Edit:
Solved by changing

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```

to

```
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        // Cookie settings
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
```

Comment: See :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1#http-some-cookie-samesite-defaults-changed-to-none and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1

Comment: thanks I had a similar problem on dotnet core 3.1 asp mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a line in your startup.cs

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

It adds the authentication middleware to your app.
You have to call it right before `app.UseAuthorization();`

So that it shows that way:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

If you follow the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio it should work fine.

Comment: I have removed 
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>{.. }); 
and added    
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        // Cookie settings
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    }); instead. 
This solved it, Thanks. (App.UseAuthentication() was there).

Comment: for ehusvjx and his solution: your solution is maybe not ideal and I think, that now you are not able to show "user cookie consent", when you clear all your cookies. the "services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => { options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true; options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None; });" is there for showing the "user cookie consent" and GDPR reason.